# Stream 3D video to Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, streaming

It is possible to stream **3D** videos to Xbox? Wich movie format should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't own an Xbox myself, but the type of files that *should* work is **Half SBS**. These are simply video files (avi, mpeg, mkv, etc.) that have the two images for 3D in the same frame, either side by side or top and bottom. Most 3D TV sets should recognize the signal as 3D and overlay the two images.

The reason I believe it should work is because these are standard video files that just happen to have two images side by side. As long as the codec/resolution is supported by the Xbox it should play them and allow the TV to recognize them as 3D and do the rest of the work.

Comment: Will try it at home and let you know. Tks!

Comment: Good reasoning, stereoscopic tech has been around for a long time so it makes sense that most formats support two images playing side-by-side. I would be surprised if there is no way to get it working on Xbox.